# How to assign meta tag image content url value depending on div class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, blogger

My goal is to have a specific image preview if my post contains specific `class/es` when sharing.

I am using blogger platform and its default codes.

```
<b:if cond='data:post.labels any (l  =&gt; l.name in {"video", "youtube"})'>
    <meta content='post-with-video-class.jpg' property='og:image'/>

<b:elseif cond='data:post.labels any (l  =&gt; l.name in {"gallery"})'/>
    <meta content='post-with-gallery-class.jpg' property='og:image'/>

<b:else/>
    <meta content='default-class-url.jpg' property='og:image'/>
</b:if>
```

...and my contents

```
<div id='posts'>
    <div class='video and youtube'>
        post 1
    </div>
    <div class='gallery'>
        post 2
    </div>
    <div class='default'>
        post 3
    </div>
</div>
```

This code will only work if it is inside the `body` and in order to have preview image, `meta` tag should be inside `head`.

I tried to append it with jquery but still there's no preview image.

```
$("[property*='og:image']").appendTo ("head");
```

Is there any jQuery code to replace the blogger code?
I'm reading about `classList` and `hasClass` but executing them is still far from my knowledge. Please help.

Comment: If you're trying to use these tags for facebook, or any other social media platform, it won't work because the meta tags need to be created on page load

Comment: I have two questions: Do you want to have the `og:image` set for the Post list webpage or the post detail webpage? which theme are you using?

Comment: @winner_joiner I want them on both page types. It's from scratch.

Comment: @88willr does my answer help, or do you need a better solution? If it helped please mark as solution.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There may be a better solution, but here is a possible workaround, that works.
*Under this assumption:*

- For the list view, one default image for the Blog should be shown.
- For the detail view, the video or gallery image will be shown.
- Post-Title can have a keyword to filter, instead of the labels.

this code can be entered into the `head`-tag, and creates the specified `meta`-tag. For this example I used the keyword ***(video)*** for the `post-with-video-class.jpg` image and the keyword ***(pics)*** for the image `post-with-gallery-class.jpg`, in any other case the default image will be shown.
  
*Any other keyword can be used, but limits the title option*

```
<b:with value='data:widgets.Blog.first.posts.first' var='post'>
    <b:if cond='data:view.isSingleItem and data:post.title contains &quot;(video)&quot;'>
        <meta content='post-with-video-class.jpg' property='og:image'/>
    <b:elseif cond="data:view.isSingleItem and data:post.title contains &quot;(pics)&quot;"/>
        <meta content='post-with-gallery-class.jpg' property='og:image'/>
    <b:else/>
        <meta content='default-class-url.jpg' property='og:image'/>
    </b:if>
</b:with>
```

It's not elegant, but a possible and more or less simple workaround.

> **Hint:** for this to work, it should be based on a *new Theme (like **Contempo**)* since some functions, tags and *data* elements are not available in older themes.
>     
>   *Here some good documentation, that might help http://template-data.blogspot.co.at*

*Since there isn't much documentation, I can't say if the `labels` property can be accessed on the `data:widgets.Blog.first.posts.first` post object.*